# Custom stylesheet not found ASP.NET Core

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core

I am in the process of trying to add some styles to a ASP.Net web app. The issue I am having is related to loading in a custom style sheet. I have the references required for bootstrap however I want to add my own custom styles sheet called CustomStyles.css, This file exists in the same directory as the file that I am adding the reference to however when I inspect the element I get a 404 could not load resource error.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      asp-fallback-href="~/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CustomStyles.css" />

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
</head>
```

Above is my attempt at loading my stylesheet directly after the Bootstrap references. I am unsure as to what I am doing wrong and I'm sure it is a small thing however I can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Make a folder named 'css' in wwwroot and refer it path in your webpage otherwise it won't work.

Comment: @noobprogrammer: There’s no requirement for it to be in the `css` sub folder, even if that’s the default used by Microsoft’s templates. And, in fact, that won’t work here without the OP changing their style sheet URL to `/css/CustomStyles.css`.

Comment: In addition to the above point regarding `wwwroot`, you also need to ensure that the `app.UseStaticFiles();` middleware is added to your `Startup` class’s `Configure()` method.